# "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" In Alexa Developer Console

Tags: python-3.x, alexa-skills-kit, flask-ask

**SITUATION:**
So i followed a 3 video short tutorial by sentdex on youtube named "Alexa Skills w/ Python and Flask-Ask" parts 1, 2 and 3. Basically when i run this skill, alexa will read me the first 10 headlines from reddit.com/ r/ worldnews (cant give more than 8 URL for this post unfortunately).

**ERROR I'M HAVING:**
I followed all steps and i keep getting this error when i test it out in the Amazon Alexa development site saying: "There was a problem with the requested skill's response". One issue i have is that the alexa development console has been updated a few months ago and is completely different so i have no clue if i did something wrong or not. All the youtube videos i have seen are on the old version which has a different way of doing things. I'm going to outline exactly what i have done and hopefully u guys could point what i did wrong.

**WHAT I TRIED:**
I will also like to mention that i have tried replacing the contents of the get_headlines function with a return command that returns a string for alexa to say like: "it works". But i got the same error message on the development site. So I'm guessing that my code is fine but i might have configured the setting in my alexa dev account wrong. Below, i have included pictures of every step i have done for this simple program.

**EXACTLY STEPS I HAVE TAKEN:**

1) I have installed flask, flask-ask, and unidecode with the pip installer

2) I downloaded ngrok to host my site

3) **CODE:** This is the code i have ran (took out my reddit username and password for obvious reasons). It has no errors and the homepage runs fine. So i guess there is no issue with the code itself.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_ask import Ask, statement, question, session
import json     
import requests 
import time
import unidecode 

app = Flask(__name__) 
ask = Ask(app, "/big_reader") 

def get_headlines(): # DESCRIPTION: get_headlines function will grab the headlines from redit and then its going "stringify" all the headlines together
    # 1) LOG INTO REDDIT API
    user_pass_dict = {
        'user': 'ENTER_YOUR_REDDIT_USERNAME',#'ENTER_YOUR_USERNAME',
        'passwd': 'YOUR_REDDIT_PASSWORD',
        'api_type': 'json'
    }
    # Requesting a session from api
    sess = requests.Session()
    sess.headers.update( {'User-Agent': 'I am testing Alexa Here'} ) 
    sess.post('https://www.reddit.com/api/login', data=user_pass_dict) 
    time.sleep(1) 

    url = 'https://reddit.com/r/worldnews/.json?limit=10' 
    html = sess.get(url)
    data = json.loads(html.content.decode('utf-8'))
    titles = [] 
    for listing in data['data']['children']:
        titles.append( unidecode.unidecode(listing['data']['title']) ) 
    titles = '...'.join([i for i in titles]) 
    return titles

################################# ALEXA STUFF ###################################################################################################
@app.route('/') 
def homepage():
    return "This is the Homepage"
# A) ALEXA ASKS SOMETHING: 
@ask.launch 
def start_skill():
    welcome_message = 'Sup, You want some news?'
    return question(welcome_message)    

# B) MY RESPONSE: 
@ask.intent("YesIntent")
def share_headlines():
    headlines = get_headlines() 
    headline_msg = 'The current world news headlines are {}'.format(headlines) #string format the headlines?
    return statement(headline_msg)
@ask.intent("NoIntent")
def no_intent():
    bye_text = 'bye'
    return statement(bye_text)

# RUN
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

4) **PICTURES OF HOW I SET UP MY ALEXA SKILL:** Here are 10 images that shows exactly what my alexa developer web page looks like

https://ibb.co/ZdMdgGF     <-- my yes intent

https://ibb.co/4N4JygL     <-- the JSON editor screen of my skill

https://ibb.co/c2HDw8h     <-- What my interface screen looks like

https://ibb.co/BP6ck2L     <--how my ngrok looks after running: ngrok http 5000

https://ibb.co/3k5J7wZ     <--copying my ngrok https address to alexa endpoint.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9X2E.jpg  <--i even tried adding "/big_reader" at the end of it.

https://ibb.co/3s3tVQH     <--the build was successful

https://ibb.co/wgF7GQ4   <--I tried to start the big reader skill and got error

Comment: Here is my Invocation screen and my no intent screen: https://ibb.co/5jK2cWy, 

https://ibb.co/N1MsQtX,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it by downgrading cryptography to 2.1.4 with `pip install cryptography==2.1.4`

Answer (score 0):

I'm hosting my own skill backend on a Raspberry Pi, using ngrok to create a tunnel between Amazon and localhost. For me this issue went away when I created and logged into my ngrok account, cut and pasted the ./ngrok authtoken  into the Linux command line, and ran the command to create the authorisation token yaml file.